# flutter ios not connecting with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am using flutter. It is compulsory to give underscore in the project name while making project in flutter. 
But when we connect it to firebase ios then it give error because firebase ios do not accept underscore in bundle id.
my package name is com.example.hello_world.

Comment: For flutter you have like 3 variables for the project. 1. Project Name, this one will create a folder structure with the project name as the root folder (good practice is to not use spaces or special chars in project name). 2. Bundle Identifier, this is a unique id for your iOS app, it should be in the form of revers namespace, again avoid using special characters (this value will be used to identify your iOS project in many places). 3. Package name, this is the "unique id" of your android app, same should be in the form of reverse namespace and again you should not use special chars here too.

Comment: but I am not able to make flutter app without underscore